# Email html output in Codeigniter email

Tags: php, email, codeigniter-3

I am having an error `Message: Undefined variable: posts`. This is what I received after I sent an email using `Codeigniter` email.

I need to send an `html` output through `CI` email.

Controller:

```php
function email() {
    $this->load->library('email');

    $config = array (
        'mailtype' => 'html',
        'wordwrap'=> TRUE,
        'charset'  => 'utf-8',
        'priority' => '1'
    );

    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->from('mywebsite.com', 'My website');
    $this->email->to('sender@gmail.com');
    $this->email->subject('Test');

    $data = $this->data['posts'] = $this->paypal->getRows();

    $message = $this->load->view('Receipt', '$data', true);

    $this->email->message($message);
    $this->email->send();   
}
```

View `Receipt.php` (this is the view I want to send in an email)

```php
foreach ($posts as $row) {
    $row->room_type;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

See how to pass data from controller to view

```
$data['posts'] = $this->paypal->getRows();

$message = $this->load->view('Receipt', $data, true);
```

No need `''` in view when you assign array to view.

Comment: It load in my current window. I don't need to load in my window/output. Just want to send in email with the output